# ASP.NET Menuitem spacing issue. (Shows page text between menuitems)

Tags: asp.net, menuitem

I am posting this quesition for my daughter who is new to ASP.Net and in school as CS major.  She is working on a website for a friend and is using the ASP Menu.  She is using images for the menuitems and has vertical submenu items.  When you mouse over the menu item and sub items pop up there is a 5 px transparent space between the items and the page text is showing through.  I don't have a copy of her code but could get it if needed.  Has anyone seen this before and know how to fix it?  Is this just a margin issue or is there some other property she should look at?

Comment: The most helpful thing would be to have her publish the code to a URL that we can view. My guess is that this problem will be resolved by good ol' CSS.

As a side note, if your daughter is a CS major, I would highly recommend that you get her involved with Stackoverflow so that she can begin learning the etiquette, search tools, etc. This will help her so much.

Comment: The site hasn't been published yet so I can't direct you to it.  I will try to get her to post her code later when she is out of class.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, great.  The important thing to remember is that .NET will resolve all of these ASP tags to regular HTML before sending them to the client, this means that you can usually use CSS to handle these issues.  I would have to see what's happening to know for sure.

Comment: She does have it online.

http://hammerednature.com/collection.aspx

Comment: And of coarse the behavior is completely different in IE and Firefox.  The issue I am talking about is in FF in IE there is a z-index issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the navigation.  But this question is only about how to hide text that appears behind the menu items so I will focus on that:

In your CSS file, find this entry:

```
.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    z-index:151;
}
```

And edit it to look like this:

```
.menu ul
{
    background-color:#F4ECE6;
    list-style: none;
    z-index:151;
}
```

Comment: Have any idea why the menu items pop up behind in IE?  I would have thought that z-index would fix that.